# "Browser is not defined" error when running firefox sample extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I have 60.4.0esr (64-bit) installed in by GNU/Linux system. When running the [find-across-tabs](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/find-across-tabs) extension I am getting the error

```
ReferenceError: browser is not defined[Learn More]
find.js:1:5
<anonymous>
file:///home/username/webextensions-examples-master/find-across-tabs/find.js:1:5
```

I am able to run  extensions like borderify correctly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the error is quite clear.  The issue here is

> ReferenceError: browser is not defined

in the:

```
let backgroundPage = browser.extension.getBackgroundPage();
```

They are probably referencing the [mozilla.org docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/extension/getBackgroundPage).  You can test the examples there to see if you are getting an error or not.

You can run the function directly in [popup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension#Sidebars_popups_options_pages).  In example:

Suppose a background script defines a function foo():

```
// background.js

function foo() {
  console.log("I'm defined in background.js");
}
```

A script running in a popup can call this function directly like this:

```
// popup.js

var page = browser.extension.getBackgroundPage();
page.foo(); // -> "I'm defined in background.js"
```

**NOTE:** The question is if you are not using private browsing mode as this function can't use with it.  This is due to [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1329304) bug.  It will always return `null`.

Comment: I am loading it as a temporary extension. How to get it working?

Comment: @user567879: now I don't understand what you mean.  Could you be more specific?